# ASP.NET MVC generic repository implementation and usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I've decided to develop a generic repository inside my ASP.NET MVC application, nevertheless I have some issues with implementation. I will try to describe my problem below.

This is my generic repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}

public interface IArtistRepository : IGenericRepository<Artist>
{
    Artist GetSingle(int fooId);
}

public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
{
    public C Context { get; set; } = new C();

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
       IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>();
       return query;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
       IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
       return query;
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
       Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
       Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
       Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
       Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Concrete implementations:

```
public class ArtistRepository :
      GenericRepository<MusicContextSqlServer, Artist>, IArtistRepository
{

    public Artist GetSingle(int artistId)
    {
       var query = GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArtistId == artistId);
       return query;
    }
}
```

Now when building controller, let's take Artist controller as example:

This will be the constructor:

```
public class ArtistsController : Controller
{
     private readonly IArtistRepository _artistRepo;

     public ArtistsController(IArtistRepository artistRepo)
     {
         _artistRepo = artistRepo;
     }
}
```

Now when it comes to Get artists, I could use:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _artistRepo.GetAll();
    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

however I also need to include `ArtistDetails` dbset, normally using context embedded inside controller I could do like this:

(db is in this case normal context embedded in controller)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var artist = db.Artist.Include(a => a.ArtistDetails);                     
    return View(artist.ToList());
}
```

But after using repositories, I am not sure where could I add this `Include()` function to make it work along my repositories. At the moment I can just do `GetAll()` coming from my repository. Same situation with call to `db.ArtistDetails` inside SelectList.

Same situation is with `Create`, normally I would use:
(db is in this case normal context embedded in controller)

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.ArtistDetails, "ArtistId", "Bio");       
     return View();       
}

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ArtistId,Name")] Artist artist)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          db.Artist.Add(artist);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.ArtistDetails, "ArtistId", "Bio", artist.ArtistId);

       return View(artist);
}
```

How can I convert those methods using repositories I use. Summarizing how to change those methods after I implemented my repository, where should I make changes and how it would look like, could anybody show solution as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of this generic repository? It looks like you are using EF, and EF is already is a generic repository in itself. Why not use DbContext directly?

Comment: Since `GetAll` returns `IQueryable<T>`, you can use the same extension methods as you use with `DbSet<T>`, which implements `IQueryable<T>` too. That is, `_artistRepo.GetAll().Include(a => a.ArtistDetails).ToList()`. But, actually, inventing your own generic repository is a bad idea. What do you do this for?

Answer (score 0):

Since you inherit a public property `Context`, which will be available for artist repository to use. I would introduce another method to `Artist repository` as below:

```
public Artist GetSingleWithDetails(int artistId)
    {
       return = Context.Set<Artist>().Include(a => a.ArtistDetails).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArtistId == artistId);

    }
```

Ideally `Context` property should be protected so that its available to subclasses but not available publicly

**EDIT**: For ArtistDetailsRepository to GetAll ArtistDetails

Interface:

```
public interface IArtistDetailsRepository : IGenericRepository<ArtistDetails>
{        
}
```

Repository:

```
public class ArtistDetailsRepository :
      GenericRepository<MusicContextSqlServer, ArtistDetails>, IArtistDetailsRepository
{   
}
```

Create:

```
ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(artistDetailRepository.GetAll.ToList(), "ArtistId", "Bio", artist.ArtistId);
```

Comment: Hi i understood that this method can be added to ArtistRepository and understand this is valid approach. What about Create? Could you also put solution in this case. Thanks Aman

Comment: @Henry you have an Add method in base repository, which the artist repository already inherits. so you can call directly using `artistrepository.Add();`

Comment: Yes there is but besides this line of code there are also: ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.ArtistDetails, "ArtistId", "Bio"); and ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.ArtistDetails, "ArtistId", "Bio", artist.ArtistId);
 what about them?

Comment: oh, I see. In that case, you'll have a separate repository for each entity, so a separate ArtistDetails Repository

Comment: ArtistDetails is 1:1 to Artist, could you show me in answer i could mark how this could look like and what could be in that repository because so far i do not see it. of course including usage with this view bag.. Thanks ! I will mark as answer afterwords

Comment: @Henry I've edited my answers and tried to answer your question with the current available information

Comment: ok so a.ArtistDetails is just like GetAll() … I am pretty new to mvc & EF